# c pointer initialisation to a number wqhich is type casted

Tags: c

In c programming, what does the following initialization means,

```
char *ptr = (char *) 100;
```

Does it means that we have initialised a pointer named `ptr` to another pointer to at location `100` which is a pointer itself. So, essentially, `100` is also pointer and we have set pointer to a pointer.

Comment: `100` itself is a constant `int` value, it doesn't have any special meaning. It's the *expression* `(char *) 100` which is a pointer to the address `100`.

Answer (score 1):

You're over thinking it. It means `ptr` is a pointer-to-char, and it points to address 100. There could be anything (or nothing) at address 100; it is implementation-defined what this code will do if you attempt to dereference that pointer.

Most architectures with an MMU will reserve the zero page and ensure that no memory can be mapped there. This means that attempting to read or write any address less than the page size (typically 4 KiB, so 0x1000) will result in a page fault, and a SIGSEGV on Linux. The purpose of this is to help catch an accidental NULL pointer dereference.

Comment: Thanks. I made that more specific.

Answer (score 0):

This expression can be used for pointers pointing to the particular address in the memory. Not used (almost) in the hosted environments, but in common use in embedded programming. Examples:

```
#define GPIOA               ((GPIO_TypeDef *) GPIOA_BASE)
#define GPIOB               ((GPIO_TypeDef *) GPIOB_BASE)
#define GPIOC               ((GPIO_TypeDef *) GPIOC_BASE)
#define GPIOD               ((GPIO_TypeDef *) GPIOD_BASE)
#define GPIOE               ((GPIO_TypeDef *) GPIOE_BASE)
```

where :

```
#define GPIOA_BASE            (0x40010000 + 0x0800)
#define GPIOB_BASE            (0x40010000 + 0x0C00)
#define GPIOC_BASE            (0x40010000 + 0x1000)
#define GPIOD_BASE            (0x40010000 + 0x1400)
#define GPIOE_BASE            (0x40010000 + 0x1800)
```